# how can i increase my C Drive space?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I have partitioned 18 GB for my C drive, even though my hard disk is 320 GB. Now I'm lacking the space to install software to my C drive.
How can I transfer or increase the size of my C drive?
I have enough space in my other drive.

Comment: Not a programming related question!

Comment: not a programming..! Need help..!

Answer (score 2):

Download and install [partition magic](http://partition-magic.soft32.com/).

> Partition Magic is a computer program that allows you to slice your hard drive up into several partitions. This allows one physical disc drive to be used as if it were several drives. Once created, the partitions can be re-sized without losing any of the data stored in them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links, they may not directly answer your question, but knowing this may help along the way:

http://lifehacker.com/5517688/how-to-upgrade-your-tiny-hard-drive-to-a-spacious-new-one-and-keep-your-data-intact

This article shows how to wipe out large files. You need to expand space, but this may help get you some space right away:

http://lifehacker.com/5511904/how-to-analyze-clean-out-and-free-space-on-your-hard-drive

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 7, you should be able to right-click on Computer and "Manage" your computer. Then go to Disk Management and right click on the C: partition and Extend it.

If the remaining 300Gigs of your HDD are already allocated (partitioned), you might need to shrink it first before you can extend the first partition.

***Note: Make sure you have a full backup of all your files before attempting any manipulation of your partitions.***